# Derive Profit Max from C(q)

Tags: derivatives, economics

Am from computer background and recently started to pick up my interest in learning economics basics for work related projects.

I do have some theoretical understanding of the very basic term , but not much.
Lets say i have a inverse Demand equation Price $= \alpha -$ Quantity, and we have many firms each producing quantity $q$. so Quantity($Q$) = sum of q's of individual firms.

And also we have cost function given by $1.3bq^2 + 50$ (I know $50$ is the Fixed price). So total cost $TC =$ Variable cost ($1.3bq^2$) + Fixed cost of $50$.

So from this equation , I can calculate the Tc for producing each quantity , by just replacing $q$ with the quantity.

But how can I calculate the profit maximization for each company without knowing the Price per quantity ? To calculate Profit max i need both $TR$ and $TC$ term if am not wrong to apply logic of $MR=MC$.

Comment: what is $MR$? what is $MC$?

Comment: None of them are given per say (Marginal Cost & Marginal Revenue). All i have is a inverse demand and Cost function in terms of quantity. But lets say MC = derivative of c(q) i get that as c'(q) = 2.6*q

Comment: First, calculate marginal revenue, given production by the other firms. $TR=Pq=(\alpha - K - q)q$ where K is total output of other firms, and q is the firm's quantity choice.  Next, set marginal revenue equals marginal cost.  This should give you a $q$ for the representative firm, and assume symmetry, so then assume all the firms produce than many--in effect, choose a number of firms. Finally, make the assumption that this is an industry in long-run equilibrium, so that for each firm, $TC\leq P$ and calculate how many firms there will be in the industry for that to hold true.

Comment: @Trurl, thanks for your solution. If i assume the market to be in Perfect competition , can i assume P= MR ?. Or should i still calculate MR from TR

Comment: If you have many firms, $P=MR$ may be a good approximation, but the derivative of TR is still the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
p(q)&=\alpha-q\\
c(q)&=50+1.3bq\\
r(q)&=p(q)\times q=\alpha q-q^2\\
\pi(q)&=r(q)-c(q)=(\alpha q-q^2)-(50+1.3bq)=(\alpha-1.3b)q-q^2-50\\
\max_q \pi(q)&=\max_q\{(\alpha-1.3b)q-q^2-50\}
\\
\pi'(q)&=(\alpha-1.3b)-2q=0\quad\Longrightarrow \quad \boxed{ q_{\max}=\frac{2}{\alpha-1.3b}}
\end{align}
$$